# Pattern not allowing words including numbers?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I wrote a program that lets me add categories, since it had some problems with special characters and numbers at the first position, I made a regex filter, which should only take care of the special characters. However, if I use a word that includes a number now, the method also returns true for some reason.

```
private boolean containsSpecChar () {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-zA-Z]");
  String a = null;
  a = txtInKategorieName.getText();
  Matcher match= pattern.matcher(a);
  Matcher m = p.matcher(a);
  if (
  match.matches() || m.matches()
  )
  {
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I want to be able to use Words containing numbers as well.
Thanks

Comment: Under what condition do you want to return `true` exactly?

Comment: `[0-9a-zA-Z]` and `[a-zA-Z0-9]` are effectively the same, i.e. they _match_ the same characters.

Comment: Why aren't you just doing `find` on anything that's *not* a letter or a number?

Comment: Also note that `Matcher.matches()` tries to match the _entire_ input, so any string longer with a length other than 1 would _not_ match. Your check "containsSpecChar" seems to be defined as "if there's a char that is not a-z, A-Z or 0-9" - so either use `return a.matches(".*[^a-zA-Z0-9].*")`, `return !a.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")` or use `Matcher.find()` along with the expression `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` (if `find()` returns true the string contains at least one character that isn't an ascii letter or digit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[a-zA-Z0-9]` and `[0-9a-zA-Z]` is the same thing.

The `[xxx]` regex pattern is a [**character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html), which matches a *single* character. If you want to match *one or more* of those characters, you need to add a `+` [quantifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy) at the end:

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want true for words containing letters and or numbers use `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` as a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `.matches` way:

```
public static boolean containsSpecChar () {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
  String a = txtInKategorieName.getText();
  Matcher match = pattern.matcher(a);

  return !match.matches();
}
```

And here is the `.find` way:

```
public static boolean containsSpecChar () {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
  String a = txtInKategorieName.getText();
  Matcher match = pattern.matcher(a);

  return match.find();
}
```